# Raspberry Pi Desktop folder reappearing after deletion

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi

I have a 10-node cluster of Raspberry Pi 4B 1GB. These have all been recently imaged with the 64bit version of RaspiOS with GUI (latest). I noticed that after I deleted the /home/pi/Desktop/ directory on my head node, it reappeared after a couple days. These are new SD cards so SD card corruption is probably not the reason. Is this a functionality of the GUI version of RaspiOS (recreating the Desktop folder) or is something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`Desktop` is a special directory that is managed by several things, including but not limited to, your desktop environment.

Following the advice of
[this superuser post](https://superuser.com/a/298744) by user MestreLion, you can prevent the `Desktop` from being recreated on login by changing the contents of `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf`.

> If you set `enabled=False`, either globally or for your own user only, special folders will not be re-created at login anymore in case you delete or rename the folders.

The rest of the advice in the linked answer can provide additional insight into customizing the `HOME` directory.